# Maximum sum path in a matrix

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming, matrices

Given a square matrix of size N X N (1 <= N <= 1000) containing positive and negative integers with absolute value not larger than 1000, we need to compute the greatest sum achievable
by walking a path, starting at any cell of the matrix and always moving downwards or rightwards.
Additionally we also have to find the number of times that this sum is achievable.

For example: 
For the matrix 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
The maximum sum is 12 and it occurs only once

Comment: Hey, this is a standard dynamic programming exercise.  What have you tried, and where are you stuck?  See also [Project Euler, Problem 18 — Maximum path sum I](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18).

Comment: The since $N=O(1)$ and the absolute value of the integers is also upper bounded by a constant, this problem can be solved in time $O(1)$ by brute force.

Answer (score 0):

As Pal have commented, this is a question in dynamic programming. I will now propose the solution using dynamic programming to the question, ***but I highly recommend trying it on your own first, and checking this later.***

---

**The algorithm:**

1. Create a new empty matrix $V$ of size N by N
2. for $1 \le i \le N:$

   3. for $1 \le j \le N:$

      4. Set $V[i, j] = M[i,j] + max(V[i-1, j], V[i, j-1])$ (note that $V[-1,j] = V[i,-1] = 0$)
3. Find $m = max_i,_j(V[i,j])$
4. Count the number of times we see $m$ in $V$
5. You can return the maximum sum $m$ and the number of times it occurs (as you have counted it)

**Complexity:**

The algorithm takes $O(N^2)$ **time** (which is $O(k)$ if we let $k$ be the input size) since it calculates a new matrix of size N by N, doing $O(1)$ operations per cell in it.

Notive that the algorithm's **space** complexity is **also** $O(N^2)$ as we were required to create a whole new matrix.